# how to perform this predictor graph witth ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

Is there a way to reproduce the attached figure in R, how to draw lines and dots in ggplot? Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxSf6.png)

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Do you have any reproducible data that you can post and any code that you've already tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.